# CMS events + invoicing software integration

Tags: web-apps, wordpress

Do you know any event managment system for Joomla or WordPress that has integration possibilities with invoicing software. I would also like the invoicing to be capable of accumulating costs for a month and send it then. I.e. If a company has several employees that will go on our events, they don't want to get invoiced for each employee separately.